# Multidimensional Array or Multidimensional arraylist

Tags: java

I have a problem in my code where I need to compare four doubles against other sets of four doubles. I tried creating a four dimensional array for this:

```
double[][][][] myArray = new double[][][][] {{{{1.1}, {1.2}, {1.3},{1.4}}}};
```

But the problem with this is I do not know the size of the array and I need to be able to add elements to it dynamically. I am unfamiliar with array lists but I was wondering if this would be the solution? Can you have mutli-dimensional array lists?

Edit to provide better explanation of the problem:

The reason I have four doubles is they store locations concering journeys.

```
Double 1 = lattitude of start location. 
Double 2 = longitude of start location.
Double 3 = lattitude of end location. 
Double 4 = longitude of end location.
```

So I have 4 doubles associated with a journey and I need to be able to take those values and compare them with other sets of 4 doubles to see if these locations are within a reasonable distance of each other. I have already resolved that side of the problem. Its just comparing one set of 4 doubles against n other sets is what I am trying to do. I ultimately want to be able to run every set off each other to determine if they are similar.

Comment: Four doubles is just one array `{1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}`.  Why would you need four dimensions?

Comment: I want to be able to compare four doubles against all other sets of four doubles in the array, that was why I thought to use 4 dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare", specifically?  Do you just want to check for equality?

Comment: Well I provided a bit more detail in the main post but basically - I have a method that which will take in its arguement the 8 values corresponding to two different journeys and determine whether they are within a suitable distance of each other. So I want to be able to pick four values (representing one journey) and compare it with all other sets of four values to show which other values are similar enough to be considered matches.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no reason to use a 4-dimensional array. No offense but this kind of code looks **ugly!**

To add elements to the array dynamically, instead use an `ArrayList<Double>`. There is no fixed size to this data structure. You could initialize it like such:

```
List<Double> dblList = Arrays.asList(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);
```

Or

```
List<Double> dblList = new ArrayList<Double>(new Double[] {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4});
```

### UPDATE

Sorry, I just realized that you want to compare multiple list to each other. But still, this answer should be able to help you.

Comment: No offense taken, I knew it was hideous just trying to figure out the best way to solve my problem. So if I declare a list like this: List<Double> dblList = new ArrayList<Double>(); how can I add 4 doubles to the list at a time. The second example you provide throws an error because the constructor ArrayList<Double>(Double[]) is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To compare sets of 4 doubles against each other, you don't need 4 dimensions, only 2.  The first dimension is for however many sets of doubles you have, and the second dimension is for the 4 doubles each.

```
double[][] myArray = new double[2 /*sets*/][4 /*doubles each*/] = {
    {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}, {2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4}};
```

If you need to add to the list, then you probably want an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>` so can add lists of 4 doubles.  Or perhaps an `ArrayList<double[]>` so that you can add arrays of 4 doubles each to a growing `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it well, what you want is a collection of an object containing four double.

This can be represented using a `List` containing some `List` of `Double`. 
This way you can use built in `equals` and `hashcode` methods of the `Collection` api of Java to make operations on your `List<Double>`.
Therefor you can have your code like this :

```
List<List<Double>> dblList = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
```

And add some lists of four `Double` to it.
The main advantage of this methods is that you can check the equality of two of your sublist using the method `equals` of the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit confused about the term "set", because that implies that order of the double values does not matter.  Based on your update to the question, I am assuming that the order *does* matter.

If all you're wanting to do is iterate through the existing values and call your method, that is pretty simple:

```
List<List<Double>> doubles = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
doubles.add(Arrays.asList(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4));
doubles.add(Arrays.asList(2.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4));
doubles.add(Arrays.asList(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4));
doubles.add(Arrays.asList(3.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4));

List<Double> newValue = Arrays.asList(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4);
for (List<Double> vals : doubles) {
    compareJourneys(newValue, vals); //this is your comparison method
}
```

If it turns out that I misinterpreted your use of the word "set", you could use a `List<Set<Double>>` instead of a `List<List<Double>>`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your problem, I don't believe a multidimensional array is suitable. Given that your four doubles, each which have significant meaning, perhaps grouping them into a class would be more meaningful. For example...

```
class JourneyCoords {
 private double latStart;
 private double latEnd;
 private double longStart;
 private double longEnd;
 JourneyCoords(double latStart,double latEnd,double longStart, double longEnd){
  this.latStart = latStart;
  this.latEnd = latEnd;
  this.longStart = longStart;
  this.longEnd = longEnd;
 }
 public Boolean isWithinReasonableDistance(JourneyCoords other){
  // What you define to be within reasonable distance
  return true;
 }
}
```

Then with an array or list of JourneyCoords objects you can run pairwise comparison between each as follows:

```
JourneyCoords[] myJourneyCoords = new JourneyCoords[10];

// Initialization of values
for(int i=0;i<myJourneyCoords.length;i++){
 myJourneyCoords = new JourneyCoords(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
}

// Pairwise comparison
for(int i=0;i<myJourneyCoords.length;i++){
 for(int j=i+1;j<myJourneyCoords.length;j++){
  if(myJourneyCoords[i].isWithinReasonableDistance(myJourneyCoords[j])){
   // These two are within reasonable distance
  }
 }
}
```

I didn't test the code, but hopefully you get the concept.